# how to use the new footables export data attribute

Tags: footable

Since most Footables functionality is added via attributes i've tried:
data-export in the opening table tag with all other footable data attributes but cant sem to get any export functionality. since the docs dont even mention how to use this feature can anyone shed any light on this ??

This is my jquery;

```
$('#clicker').on('click', function()
{
    var csv = FooTable.get("#tblBalanceOverview").toCSV(true);
    $("#showcsv").text(csv);    
});
```

NOTE: clicker is an element just above the defined footable on the same page
'showcsv' is an empty paragraph element just so i can see if any thing is produced.

Answer (score 3):

the javascript variable csv will contain the result rows.
Now all you need is to create a download file:
this is the footable table container:

```html
<div class="container">
  <table id="table-edit" class="table-hover table table-striped">
  </table>
</div> <!-- /container -->
```

this is the excel export button:

```html
<button class="btn btn-warning excelexport btn-md" type="button">export</button>
```

This is the javascript function for the export triggerd by the button click:

```js
$(".excelexport").on("click", function (e) {
    var csv = FooTable.get('#table-edit').toCSV(true);
    /*  console.log ("csv: " + csv);*/
    var hiddenElement = document.createElement('a');
    hiddenElement.href = 'data:text/csv;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURI(csv);
    hiddenElement.target = '_blank';
    hiddenElement.download = 'SDTB_DM_010_LICENSES_DONGLES_ACT.csv';
    hiddenElement.click();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Even the below code works fine.

Reference: https://github.com/fooplugins/FooTable/issues/634#issuecomment-404630961

```
/* ############ export table footable to excel ############ */
/* bind the button "excel Export" to load the rows */
    $(".excelexport").on("click", function (e) {
    var filename = "filename.csv";
    var csv = FooTable.get('#table-footable').toCSV();
    var blob = new Blob([ csv ], {
        type : "application/csv;charset=utf-8;"
    });
    if (window.navigator.msSaveBlob) {
        // FOR IE BROWSER
        navigator.msSaveBlob(blob, filename);
    } else {
        // FOR OTHER BROWSERS
        var link = document.createElement("a");
        var csvUrl = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
        link.href = csvUrl;
        link.style = "visibility:hidden";
        link.download = filename;
        document.body.appendChild(link);
        link.click();
        document.body.removeChild(link);
    }
});
```